# Magento 2.1 spam users even when captcha is enabled

Tags: customer, captcha, magento-2.1.10

In **Magento 2.1.10**, I have successfully enabled **captcha for customer registration form** but I am still getting fake users registered on website.

This is the registration form:
[image]

These are fake users in admin:
[image]

I have tested the registration form and it seems to be working fine. Then from where these users are getting registered and how to prevent this?

Comment: When was the captcha enable, as the registrations seem to have done around 3 days back.

Comment: It was enabled last week on 12th July.

Comment: you can see in access log where is the POST request made to /customer/account/createpost/

Comment: @MagenX Where can I find this access log? there is no such file in var/log directory

Answer (score 1):

I know what can help you to protect your website from spam. Cleantalk provides spam protection that is invisible for visitors without using captcha and other annoying methods. When installed on your website this service captures the behaviour parameters of a visitor or a spambot. These parameters are being assessed and the service makes a decision — to register the visitor or to define the form as spam and reject it. Based on such checks, the service forms its own list of email addresses used by spambots. By the way, the tool adds not only email addresses to the blacklist, but also IP addresses and domains of the websites that are promoted through spam mailout.